# Paypal Express Checkout NVP unable to processes order with this account

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I am trying to implement Paypal Express checkout with my site.
I am able to generate the token using the "SetExpressCheckout" API call, and the user is redirected to the Paypal login page.
However, once the user logs in, they get the following error:

We're not able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please try again later.

This only happens on the live production. When using the sandbox everything seems to work.

I would really appreciate any suggestions as to what may be causing this and how to fix it, TIA!

Comment: Is the live account a business account or is it a personal account?

Comment: Are you working in the sandbox or live?

Comment: Live, like I posted in my question, in sandbox everything works

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that.  PayPal is notorious for cookie issues.  Can you try a clean browser that you don't normally use, or clear the cookies / cache in your current browser and see if that changes anything?